# Create a PDF using iTextSharp from HTML page with external CSS in a Web Service

Tags: c#, html, css, pdf, itext

I have a js file that call a webservice to create a pdf of an html page I have. I'm using iTextSharp library for that, and I pass the html string as parameter of the web service to create it's pdf, but I want to keep the design. How can I do that. I have seen a lot of tutorial a try to implement the code without success.

Comment: The error is in line 42 of your code.

Comment: You write you tried *to implement the code without success.* What was the problem? A. The code didn't compile. B. The code compiled, but had runtime errors. C. The code executed, but the result wasn't as expected. D. Something else. If your answer is C: please explain what you expected, and share the original HTML, the C# code, and the resulting PDF. Note that I am assuming that you used iText 7 + pdfHTML as described in the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml). If not, then that's your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all. I already made some tricks to keep design of html when created pdf in server side with iTextSharp. I add manually some clases to the css resolver just like this:

StyleAttrCSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
cssResolver.AddCssFile(Context.Server.MapPath("/Content/FOUNDATION/css/PDF.css"), true);
cssResolver.AddCss(".fontSizeTb table, td {font-size: 12px; }", true);
cssResolver.AddCss(".ChangeH3 {font-size: 16px; padding-top: 20px; margin-top: 20px; vertical-align: bottom;}", true);

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK iTextSharp does not have an HTML layout engine (which is what you'll need to keep your design intact).

If your layout is simple then A Google search of "HTML to Pdf .NET component" will yield tons of results.

Our ActivePDF WebGrabber product will do that for you, but it might be overkill for a simple web service with low volume.

Comment: *"AFAIK iTextSharp does not have an HTML layout engine"* - then your knowledge is a bit outdated.

Comment: Hi Tim, long time no see. Please check out the [iText 7 HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) to learn more about iText's HTML layout engine. By the way: have you already looked into Next Generation PDF? I suggest that you remove your answer. I would have down-voted it, but as a rule, I avoid down-voting posts from people with a reputation of 1 (since people with a reputation of 1 are usually newbies who still need to learn how Stack Overflow works).